# How to connect two excel files given a filter?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Suppose that there are 2 excel files:

first is

```
expenses amount
CCL      12usd
FFL      25usd
CCL      12usd
FFL      25usd
FCL      10usd
```

second is

```
name id expenses
A    12 CCL
B    13 FCL
C    14 FFL
D    15 CCL
```

I want to filter first file by expenses type, for ex: "CCL" and find info from second file with matched expenses type

And get following results in another spreadsheet:

```
name  id  expenses amount 
A     12  CCL      12usd
D     15  CCL      12usd
```

I am not familiar with VBA yet, but is it possible write a macro to automate a procedure? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this example is complete. How do you know that id=12 corresponds to 12usd and id=15 corresponds to 12usd? There's no unique identifier of the records in the first sheet.

Comment: How to know Amount column will fit the data in second table?

Comment: @AlexM, the unique **identifier** in this case is **type** **of** **expenses**. For example for expenses "CCL" is 12 usd and for type of expenses "FFL" is 25 usd. for each name corresponding ID exists ( as if each student has his own ID in the system)

Answer (score 1):

Put "CCL" in A1 of your 3rd workbook.

2nd row is for headers.
[image: example]

**Array** formulas are entered not using regular <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A3 has this *array* formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Temp\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$5,SMALL(IF('C:\Temp\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$1:$C$5=$A$1,ROW('C:\Temp\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$1:$C$5),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

B3 has this *array* formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Temp\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF('C:\Temp\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$1:$C$5=$A$1,ROW('C:\Temp\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$1:$C$5),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

C3 has this formula:

```
=IF(A3<>"",$A$1,"")
```

D3 has this *array* formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Temp\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$1:$B$6,MATCH(C3,'C:\Temp\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$6,0)),"")
```